# Format genereated HTML syntax when using AppendHtmlLine in Tag Helper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I generate some html in a tag helper and was wondering if its possible to format the generated html with indents like the html generated by the tag helper.

**HTML from tag helper**:

```
<span class="lc-p-img-zoom">
    <img src ="/GRAPHIC/bg-laptop-min.jpg" class="lc-p-img-zoom-cover-img lc-p-zoom-img-test" />

    <section class="lc-p-zoom-img-wrap">
        <img src="/Custom/Folder/test1.jpg" class="lc-p-img-zoom-item zoomClass" />
        <img src="/GRAPHIC/test2.jpg" class="lc-p-img-zoom-item zoomClass" />
        <img src="/GRAPHIC/test3.jpg" class="lc-p-img-zoom-item zoomClass" />
    </section>
</span>
```

**HTML from my code**:

```
<span class="lc-p-img-zoom">
<img src ="/GRAPHIC/demo2.jpg" class="lc-p-img-zoom-cover-img lc-p-zoom-img-test" />
<section class="lc-p-zoom-img-wrap">
<img src ="/GRAPHIC/zoom.jpg" class="zoomClass" />
</section>
</span>
```

**Code in tag helper**:

```
string img = this.ZoomSrc.IsNullOrEmpty() ? this.Src : this.ZoomSrc, folder = this.ZoomFolderPath.IsNullOrEmpty() ? this.FolderPath : this.ZoomFolderPath;
HtmlContentBuilder section = new HtmlContentBuilder();

section.AppendHtmlLine("<section class=\"" + WrapClassName + "\">");              
section.AppendLine(GetImgTag(GetPath(img, folder), this.ZoomClass));
section.AppendHtmlLine("</section>");

output.Content.SetHtmlContent(section);
```

Comment: huh?  You are generating the html in the tag helper, but you are wondering if it can be formatted like html generated by the tag helper?  You are describing the same process twice and wanting to figure out how to get the same results?

Comment: nope. if the tag contains children I let the tag helper generate the html, if not I have to generate the html myself. thanks for asking

Comment: So where is your code that generates the HTML?  Is it the one you have labeled "Code in tag helper"?  Your question is not clear to me.  Hope I am not being dense.

Comment: yes the code in tag helper generates the listed html without idents, but when the tag helper generated html it looks "pretty". I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the code looks a little nicer, but the code works fine as it is. just want to make it look nice if someone is looking at the page source :)